# can't find self.connection.report documentation for comet_ml

Tags: python, init, comet-ml

I installed comet_ml on conda and after trying to run my code, it's giving the error

```
 File "/Users/christhomas/miniforge3/envs/condenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/comet_ml/__init__.py", line 345, in _report
self.connection.report(*args, **kwargs)    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'report'
```

This is the definition in the comet_ml **init**.py file:

```
def _report(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.connection.report(*args, **kwargs)
```

Can't seem to find anything referencing this online. Anyone got any ideas?